# Azure AD login with forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory

I have a solution where Forms Authentication in place, now I am trying to integrate azure along with Forms Authentication so that when they choose Login using AD it will navigate to portal and get the response. In the POC I developed it works fine where it has no Forms Authentication, but when I integrate with the actual application it is not getting navigated to portal

```
private void AzureLogin() {
    HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
    new MailAddress(txtUsername.Text).Host);
}
```

It is always redirecting to default page instead of navigating. I have commented the FormsAuthentication section in web.config but still it is navigating to login page

Comment: Could you please refer this similar threads in SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999304/mixing-azure-ad-authentication-with-forms-authentication , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030785/forms-and-azure-ad-authentication , and https://forums.asp.net/t/2169041.aspx?Forms+authentication+with+AD+

Answer (score 0):

Your application is redirecting you to the default page instead of navigating due to this code:

`new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },`

Update this line then to `new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/login"}` and this should redirect your application to the login page. By setting this RedirectUri property means you are setting the full path which is used as an HTTP [redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.authentication.authenticationproperties?view=aspnetcore-2.2) response value.

[image]

Learn more about the auth code flow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens) for access tokens.

Comment: `new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },` This was setup in startup but the problem is with FormsAuthentication so I turned it off then I got this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69192051/idx21323-requirenonce-is-pii-is-hidden-openidconnectprotocolvalidationcont